# .NET 6.0 DI Service Registration Issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, .net-6.0

I am using a repository pattern and trying to register services in .NET 6.0 using DI.

In `Program.cs`,

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDomain, Domain>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApiUserRepository, ApiUserRepository>();
```

My classes:

```cs
public class ApiUserRepository : IApiUserRepository
{
    public ApiUserRepository(Domain domain) { }
}

public class Domain : IDomain
{
    public Domain(IConfiguration configuration) { }
}
```

I am getting the following exception,

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Repositories.Domain' while attempting to activate 'Repositories.ApiUserRepository'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the constructor of `ApiUserRepository` to inject `IDomain` in stead of `Domain`

`Domain` is registered only as `IDomain`, so `Domain` itself cannot be resolved.

Alternatively you can register the `Domain` class.